# Include mods-in-room/room owner information in chat flags

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools, chat-flags

There's been a lot of recent discussion about chat. One thing that came up is the "blue flood"/"mod invasion", which is the tendency to have a rush of moderators show up in a chat room following a flag.

Although the flag links to the transcript in an effort to provide context, sometimes I feel that more intervention is required than simply actioning a flag, but I can't tell if there is a site moderator or room owner already present in the room when I'm viewing the transcript.

Can we add which site moderators and room owners are currently present to the flag? I think this information (which is available but time-consuming to find) would further reduce an increase in traffic following a flag.

Comment: But if there are moderators in the rooms, should the flags have arisen in the first place? On first glance (albeit without context), it seems to be flag abuse somewhat.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing which could prevent the blue tide: Don't push flags outside the room if there is a moderator active in the room already. In the Bridge there are almost always moderators active, and flags can be handled without needing to broadcast for aid.

Maybe an even simpler way of doing this is to just delay the broadcast of a flag by [30?] seconds. No response from within the room within that time? Broadcast it.

Comment: I like the idea, but what if the mods are present but not active, e.g., they are logged in but sleeping?

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Yeah, that's why I thought of the timeout - it would prevent a "mods r asleep post [x]" situation.

Comment: From some time back in chat, [this message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8379622#8379622): "AlUmmatمجاهد For starters, I never saw the flag. Which is a bit moronic, given that I was in the room when it was casted. It went to a couple of moderators but not to the site's moderator that was in the room."